# django_migrations table not update

Tags: python, django, migration

After modifying a model, I run:

`python manage.py makemigrations MYAPP`

and then I apply the migration:

`python manage.py migrate MYAPP`

I get `Applying MYAPP.0010_auto_20180406_1453... OK` and if I look to the table with MySQL commands, the modification is applied. However I get:

`python manage.py showmigrations --list
...
MYAPP
... 
[ ] 0010_auto_20180406_1453
...`

It seems that the table `django_migrations` was not updated. Why?